# How can I get divs with borders to line up when percentages sum up the same?

Tags: angular-material

Using Angular Material's flexbox I'm having trouble getting divs with margins and borders to line up.

I'm wanting to have a row with 3 boxes each taking up 1/3 of the horizontal space, followed by a row with 2 boxes - the first having 1/3 and the second having 2/3 of the space. This works fine if I don't have margins around the boxes but with margins it breaks.

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<body layout="column" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>
   Borders of divs with margins don't line up

  <div class="with-margins">
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex="33">Test</div>
        <div flex="66">Test66</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex="33">Test</div>
        <div flex="33">Test33</div>
        <div flex="33">Test33</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  Borders of divs without margins line up fine
  <div class="no-margins">
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex="33">Test</div>
        <div flex="66">Test66</div>
    </div>
    <div layout="row">
        <div flex="33">Test</div>
        <div flex="33">Test33</div>
        <div flex="33">Test33</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width : 100%;
  background-color: #dedede; 
  padding: 2px;
}

div {
  background-color : #c14543;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.with-margins>div>div {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

body>div,
body>div>div {
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
}

div.no-margins {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here's a codepen demonstrating my issue.
http://codepen.io/craigsh/pen/ZWxGEQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that margin takes extra spaces.

I think you probably just need to restructure your layout. does this work for you?
see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNYqLG

I replaced one div to span just to quickly avoid your div background css.

```
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
    <div flex="33">Test</div>
    <div flex="66">Test66</div>
</div>
<div layout="row" layout-margin>
    <div flex="33">Test</div>
    <span flex="66" layout="row">
      <div flex>Test33</div>
      <span flex="none" style="width:15px"></span>
      <div flex>Test33</div>
    </span>  
</div>
```

The idea behind is to make sure every row has the same structure, but each cell may have its own layout.

Comment: Thanks - I figured as much - I just thought there might be a more elegant way.